# Not understanding why i can't call a function

Tags: php, function

I am fairly new to PHP. And I really don't understand why I can not call a function.

```
class test {

    public function sayHi($name, $age)
    {
        echo $name . $age;
    }
}
```

When trying to call `sayHi` it does not show up.

Thank you for any input

Comment: where you are called that function.share full code

Comment: Well just below the function.

Comment: Where is below the function? If you're calling it inside the class then you can use `$this->sayHi();`

Comment: Just a note; instead of `echo $name . $age;` you should `return $name . $age` and then you would `echo $this->sayHi()` . Welcome to OOP!

Comment: Oh i see, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you are creating a function inside a class 'test', so you have to call it via a class object. example:

```
$testObj = new test();
$testObj->sayHi("Jon", 43);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class test {

public function sayHi($name, $age)
 {
 echo $name . $age;
 }
}

$testObject = new test();

$testObject->newTest();

$testObject->sayHi("Name",23);
```

Copying from : [Calling a function within a Class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725165/calling-a-function-within-a-class-method)

Comment: This line $testObject->newTest(); may confuse to @Robertme. There is no such function declaration inside your code!