# Call to function in function in class (PHP)

Tags: php, function, class

Very simple setting, but I simply don't get it...

*functions.php*

```
class functions {
    function output_functions() {
        function sendMail($to, $subject, $message){
            //...code...
        }
    }
}
```

*myfile.php*

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."some/subfolders/functions.php";

$myFunction = new functions();
$myFunction->output_functions()->sendMail("mail@mail.com","My Subject","My Message");
```

And I'm getting the Error:

> Call to a member function sendMail() on null

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: wrong syntax and mistakes ; `sendMail` has been declared as an inner, private function, inside `output_functions` so you can't access it outside. and by the way, `output_functions` returns nothing, so this is also nonsense.

Comment: How about turning your method as protected or public?

Comment: You would probably be better of (?) creating a separate class `output_functions` if you needed to split them from other types of methods.

Comment: @Pierre unfortunately it's not nonsense, this file is used in TYPO3. To use these functions they actually have to be nested this way.

Comment: @Bits Please I already tried. It's not possible to make sendMail() public.

Comment: @Nigel Ren Unfortunately I can't change the scructure (TYPO3 requirement)

Comment: @user3532637 How about making constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group your functions by type (output_functions, input_functions, whatever) I'd do a different class for each. You then should define them as public or private.

As it already has been said, nested functions cannot be accesed from outside, they're just available inside the scope of the function in which they are defined.

Comment: Thanks! I think, this is it. It's no possible to access nested function from outside.

Comment: so this was really nonsense the way you wrote it on your post !

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find such a syntax?

```
class Helper_Output {

  static public function sendMail($to, $subject, $message){
            //...code...
        }
}

//and usage: 
Helper_Output::sendMail("mail@mail.com","My Subject","My Message");
```

Comment: Just a opinion but static methods are bad for testing / code reuse.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19232836/3532637

Answer (score 0):

```
class Methods1 {
  public function do1() {
    echo __FUNCTION__ . PHP_EOL;
  }

  public function do2() {
    echo __FUNCTION__ . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

class Methods2 {
  public function do1() {
    echo __LINE__ . PHP_EOL;
  }

  public function do2() {
    echo __LINE__ . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

class Factory {
  public function getMethods1() {
    static $cache = new Methods1;

    return $cache;

  }

  public function getMethods2() {
    static $cache = new Methods2;

    return $cache;

  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$factory = new Factory;
$factory->getMethods1()->do1();
$factory->getMethods1()->do2();
$factory->getMethods2()->do1();
$factory->getMethods2()->do2();
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to include at least some explanation of how the solution works and how it solves OP's problem

Comment: @WilliamPerron yes, but this code is so simple and self explaining. Two methods that returns two different classes with different methods. Just as the topic creator wanted to do.